# Knockout.js: How to have values change based on changes in an observable array?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, observable

I have a Knockout.JS observable array that is the basis for a list:

```
  self.list_elements = ko.observableArray([
     new list_element("0001", "product 1", "3.99")
  ]);
```

Variables in this array are observables:

```
function list_element ( id, name, price ) {
   this.item_id = ko.observable(id);
   this.item_name = ko.observable(name);
   this.item_price = ko.observable(price);
}
```

There is also a details view, which I want to fill with the data of a list element that is clicked, e.g:

```
<span data-bind="text: an_item_id"></span>
```

The function to fill this gets the respective array item from the click handler.

```
self.fill_form = function ( array_item ) {
    // array_item is the array element corresponding to the selected list element
}
```

How can I connect the details view with the values in the array so that changing the value in the array shows up in the details view?

Comment: IS the detail view like a master/detail, where the detail shows a *selected* item, or is the detail view just a list of the whole array?

Comment: Details view shows a selected item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, you would create a `selected` observable and populate it with the currently selected item.  Then, you would use the `with` to render a section with a context specific to the selected item.

Something like:

```
var ViewModel = function() {
    var self = this;
    this.list_elements = ko.observableArray([...]);

    this.selected = ko.observable();

    this.fill_form = function(item) {
        self.selected(item);
    };
};
```

Then, you would bind a section like:

```
<div data-bind="with: selected">
   ...
</div>
```

If you don't need to perform any logic in your `fill_form` function, then you can even just bind a click directly against your selected observable, as the item will get passed as the first argument to the observable (which is a function) and to set its value.

Here is a sample example: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/YPKk2/

Comment: Thanks. Definitely makes handling the values in there easier.